Facing an issue with the geolocator dependency in flutter Once add to the pubspec
I'm facing an issue with the geolocator dependency in flutter.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  geolocator: ^12.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

Once I add the geolocator to the pubspec, the app stop latching in the emulator.
I tried one time to adding permissions, then latest ext. kotlin_version, also import geolocator in the main, and other solutions but still not working in the Android emulator.
I tried one time to add the permissions in the AndroidManifest.
Then latest ext.kotlin_version until '2.0.0'
Also import geolocator in the main, and other solutions but still not working in the android emulator when I press run.
I even started a new project just to add and test geolocator, but even though the new project is not responding as soon as I add geolocator to the pubspec.yam

It will be better if you can add the geolocator relevant code and the changes you did in android folder. Before using any of the geolocator features you need to ask for permission otherwise it will not work. By permission I didn't mean the uses-permission in manifest but you need to request permission from user for location access via the geolocation request permission fn. That's why I said to add the code, so that we can better idea of what you have done.

in some cases it can be solved be reduce the version of   geolocator: ^12.0.0
geolocator: ^10.0.0
geolocator: ^8.0.0
until latching
